# Is there any way to mirror fps content using AVPlayerLayer, currently getting black screen with audio

Tags: avplayer, quicktime, drm, avplayerlayer, fairplay

I am using **AVPlayerLayer** to play the **fps/DRM enabled** (**FairPlay**) protected content video in iOS application. When we are trying to **mirror the  content** to the external screen **using airplay or lightning cable** it start **showing black screen with audio only** in external screen and in the iOS device as well. All **other components are showing perfectly** on external screen and also in iOS device. The same behaviour is observed when trying to mirror using **quick time player**.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, anyone help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There can be some issues with players ignoring what they think are duplicate license requests when mirroring content which will give the symptoms you are seeing - see this Shaka issue:

- https://github.com/google/shaka-player/issues/2177

However, this can also be the desired behaviour indicated by the FairPlay license that is delivered.

You will need to discuss this with your DRM provider - FairPlay licenses can include information telling the device whether it is allowed support AirPlay, HDMI etc for the particular content being played.

These options are usually configured on the DRM provider side, often with different rules for different content categories or even for different individual content titles.

Comment: In the FairPlay Streaming section,**Block AirPlay** and **Block AVAdapter** is unchecked. Also HDCP is set to **Not Required** setting (Among Not required, Type 0 and Type 1). Still we are not able to mirror the content and getting black screen with audio only. Could you please help us so that we can mirror fps content on external device? However for non fps protected content, we are able to mirror the content without any issue.